# Laravel expiring session after submitting any form

Tags: php, laravel, session

When I am submitting my forms in laravel, the user session expires and it logs out the current user. I thought it was a csrf token problem, so I disabled its verification but the problem persists.

My view

```
 <form action="{{url('/save-user-details')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                >
                    @csrf    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Primeiro Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                    name="firstName" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Apelido</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <button type="submit" class="button pull-right" value="">Actualizar Perfil</button>    
                    </form>
```

My Route list

```
Route::post('/save-user-details', 'DashboardController@saveUser');
Route::get('/editar-usuario', 'DashboardController@editProfile');
```

My Controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function saveUser(Request $request){
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);

        $detalhes = new Detalhesuser;
        $detalhes->user_id = $user_id;
        $detalhes->firstName = $request->input('firstName');
        $detalhes->lastName = $request->input('lastName');
        $detalhes->profissao = $request->input('profissao');
        $detalhes->instituicao = $request->input('instituicao');
        $detalhes->biografia = $request->input('biografia');
        $detalhes->save();
        $user->detalhesUser_id = $detalhes->id;
        $user->save();


    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Detalhes salvos');
}
```

My sessions are being stored in a file. I tried to change it to database, the problem still persisted.

Any idea where I may be doing this wrong?

Comment: Are you using web routes or api routes?

Comment: The routes you defined doesn't seem to line up with the names of the methods in your controller...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. There is a lot of code here. If you are able to delete any of it and narrow the focus of your question then other users will be able to provide more precise answers.

Comment: I am using web routes.@AaronSaray I corrected them now, that was a test.  @NickSurmanidze

Comment: are you sure the user has access to `/dashboard` in your application?

Comment: Yes I am. Note this problem isn't just related to this particular form. If I create a blank form, where the controller function just searches for a post_id. It automatically logs the user out, and redirect to the login page

Comment: Do you have any custom middleware? If so, can you post it?

Comment: No. I don't any